# Regex Optional Second Variable and Avoid Duplicates

Tags: python, regex

I am iterating through a data frame with text in one of the columns and using two lists (pull and pull_2) as my regex matches. I want to match on the elements of the first list (pull) but want the elements of the second list to be optional. Also, when there is a match on both, I do not want to match on the elements from the first list again to avoid duplicates. However, my current code is matching when there is a match from both lists. Below is an example of the desired output.

```
pull = ['TEST', 'WORK']
pull_2 = ['MATCH', 'FINE']
```

A single row of text (one column):

```
'abc abc abcd abcde abc TEST MATCH abc WORK abc abc TEST FINE abc abcd WORK FINE abc abc WORK MATCH abc TEST'
```

Finally, the desired output should be a list of lists, like so:

```
[['TEST MATCH'], ['WORK'], ['TEST FINE'], ['WORK FINE'], ['WORK MATCH'], ['TEST']]
```

As shown above, all elements from the first list were matches including the optional ones from the second list, while also NOT matching on the elements from the first list twice when it had matches from both lists.

Below is a snippet of my code. The elements from both lists match easily as there is only a single space between them. I thought using the '?' would make those matches in the second list optional.

I appreciate the help!

```py
ts = []

for i, r in df.iterrows():
    tl = []
    for x in pull:
        for i in pull_2:
            z = re.findall(rf'{x} {i}?' , r['text'])

            tl.append(z)
    
    ts.append(tl)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose `{i}` in `(?:)` to make the whole thing optional. At present you are only making the last letter in `i` optional (for your sample data the regex is `foo bar?` which matches `foo ba` or `foo bar`). i.e. change

```py
re.findall(rf'{x} {i}?' , r['text'])
```

to

```py
re.findall(rf'{x} (?:{i})?' , r['text'])
```

Note that you need to use a non-capturing group `(?:)` so that `re.findall` doesn't return only the content of the matching group.

Also it would be more robust to use word boundaries (`\b`) to ensure you are only matching the exact `x` and `i` words:

```py
re.findall(rf'\b{x}(?:\s+{i})?\b' , r['text'])
```

To avoid the issue of getting duplicate results (for example when matching `foo` in `xxxx xxxx xxx foo bar xxxx foo xxx xxx` with multiple `i` values), combine all the `pull` and `pull_2` values into the regex using alternations. For example:

```py
pull = ['TEST', 'WORK']
pull_2 = ['MATCH', 'FINE']
r = { 'text' : 'abc abc abcd abcde abc TEST MATCH abc WORK abc abc TEST FINE abc abcd WORK FINE abc abc WORK MATCH abc TEST' }

rgx = re.compile(r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(pull) + ')(?:\s+(?:' + '|'.join(pull_2)+ r'))?\b')
rgx.findall(r['text'])
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
['TEST MATCH', 'WORK', 'TEST FINE', 'WORK FINE', 'WORK MATCH', 'TEST']
```

Comment: It seems I am still getting duplicates when the two list I am using to match have more than one element in them.

Comment: @BillFraz please see my edit; that should resolve your issue with duplications

Comment: Your edited solution matches my edited example perfectly. I appreciate your help and expertise!

Comment: What is the purpose of the + r'))?\b') at the end? Thanks again.

Comment: @BillFraz it's just closing the brackets around the optional part and adding a word boundary so that `bar` doesn't match `bark` for example. If you look at your sample data, that gives us `'\b(?:TEST|WORK)(?:\s+(?:MATCH|FINE))?\b'` as the regex string. You can see this working (and explained) here: https://regex101.com/r/frJv1Q/1